# After upgrading to spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE ,Eclipse fails to debug/run on 90% of the times

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

After upgrading to spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE (from 1.5) ,Eclipse fails to debug/run on 90% of the times
It tends to fail more on "debug" than on "run"

Windows 10

Java 11 hotspot

eclipse: Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)

spring boot = '2.2.5.RELEASE'

hibernate-core ='5.4.12.Final'

In most cases there is no message of any kind but in some cases i get this error: (most of the file up to the limit)

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fffe9a66ed6, pid=12948, tid=6660
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.4+11) (build 11.0.4+11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.4+11, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x5c6ed6]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:3175 -javaagent:C:\dev\eclipse\java-2019-092\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\229\0\.cp\lib\javaagent-shaded.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.bgprotect.EmbeddedMain --spring.config.location=file:///C:/Users/User/conf/embedded_application.yml --spring.profiles.active=dev

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz, 4 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.329)
Time: Mon Mar  9 16:54:24 2020 Jerusalem Standard Time elapsed time: 74 seconds (0d 0h 1m 14s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000019d8a9bd000):  GCTaskThread "GC Thread#1" [stack: 0x0000003052600000,0x0000003052700000] [id=6660]

Stack: [0x0000003052600000,0x0000003052700000],  sp=0x00000030526fe0b0,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x5c6ed6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x58e1f2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2c1455]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2c0ed9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x6d2517]
V  [jvm.dll+0x6d29a0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x304015]
V  [jvm.dll+0x303b18]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2d5f50]
V  [jvm.dll+0x737060]
V  [jvm.dll+0x6cd85c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x5d6286]
C  [ucrtbase.dll+0x20e72]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x17bd4]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6ced1]

JavaThread 0x0000019de58fe000 (nid = 16024) was being processed
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 1363  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.4 (0 bytes) @ 0x0000019df5a6a20b [0x0000019df5a6a140+0x00000000000000cb]
J 1441 c1 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.4 (43 bytes) @ 0x0000019dee7f412c [0x0000019dee7f3da0+0x000000000000038c]
j  java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/CodeSource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+12 java.base@11.0.4
J 5098 c2 jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.4 (64 bytes) @ 0x0000019df5dfc9a0 [0x0000019df5df8a20+0x0000000000003f80]
J 4698 c2 jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.4 (143 bytes) @ 0x0000019df5d5363c [0x0000019df5d52d20+0x000000000000091c]
J 5097 c2 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.4 (7 bytes) @ 0x0000019df5dd2c4c [0x0000019df5dd2be0+0x000000000000006c]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.FieldAttributeAppender$ForInstrumentedField.apply(Lnet/bytebuddy/jar/asm/FieldVisitor;Lnet/bytebuddy/description/field/FieldDescription;Lnet/bytebuddy/implementation/attribute/AnnotationValueFilter;)V+4
j  net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$FieldPool$Record$ForExplicitField.apply(Lnet/bytebuddy/jar/asm/ClassVisitor;Lnet/bytebuddy/implementation/attribute/AnnotationValueFilter$Factory;)V+71
j  net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/scaffold/TypeInitializer;Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/scaffold/TypeWriter$Default$ClassDumpAction$Dispatcher;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/scaffold/TypeWriter$Default$UnresolvedType;+424
j  net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/TypeResolutionStrategy$Resolved;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Unloaded;+38
j  net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/TypeResolutionStrategy;Lnet/bytebuddy/pool/TypePool;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Unloaded;+132
j  net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/TypeResolutionStrategy;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Unloaded;+5
j  net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make()Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Unloaded;+4
j  net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make()Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Unloaded;+4
j  org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.make(Lnet/bytebuddy/pool/TypePool;Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Builder;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Unloaded;+26
j  org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.make(Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Builder;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Unloaded;+3
j  org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.lambda$load$0(Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;+14
j  org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState$$Lambda$620.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+12
j  net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Ljava/lang/Class;+20
j  net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Ljava/lang/Class;+4
j  net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;+26
j  net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;+6
j  org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(Ljava/lang/Class;Lnet/bytebuddy/TypeCache;Lnet/bytebuddy/TypeCache$SimpleKey;Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Class;+16
j  org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.loadProxy(Ljava/lang/Class;Lnet/bytebuddy/TypeCache$SimpleKey;Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Class;+8
j  org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyHelper.buildProxy(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;+54
j  org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.postInstantiate(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Set;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/hibernate/type/CompositeType;)V+55
j  org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;Lorg/hibernate/property/access/spi/Getter;Lorg/hibernate/property/access/spi/Setter;)Lorg/hibernate/proxy/ProxyFactory;+90
j  org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/tuple/entity/EntityMetamodel;Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;)V+198
j  org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/tuple/entity/EntityMetamodel;Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;)V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1855  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (0 bytes) @ 0x0000019df5aaa236 [0x0000019df5aaa1c0+0x0000000000000076]
J 1854 c1 jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (89 bytes) @ 0x0000019dee8d071c [0x0000019dee8cfac0+0x0000000000000c5c]
J 1837 c1 jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (9 bytes) @ 0x0000019dee8ca5fc [0x0000019dee8ca4e0+0x000000000000011c]
J 1836 c1 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (76 bytes) @ 0x0000019dee8c9ed4 [0x0000019dee8c9c40+0x0000000000000294]
j  org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/hibernate/tuple/entity/EntityMetamodel;Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;)Lorg/hibernate/tuple/entity/EntityTuplizer;+70
j  org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(Lorg/hibernate/EntityMode;Lorg/hibernate/tuple/entity/EntityMetamodel;Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;)Lorg/hibernate/tuple/entity/EntityTuplizer;+57
j  org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;Lorg/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionFactoryImplementor;)V+1786
j  org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;Lorg/hibernate/cache/spi/access/EntityDataAccess;Lorg/hibernate/cache/spi/access/NaturalIdDataAccess;Lorg/hibernate/persister/spi/PersisterCreationContext;)V+207
j  org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;Lorg/hibernate/cache/spi/access/EntityDataAccess;Lorg/hibernate/cache/spi/access/NaturalIdDataAccess;Lorg/hibernate/persister/spi/PersisterCreationContext;)V+6
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1855  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (0 bytes) @ 0x0000019df5aaa236 [0x0000019df5aaa1c0+0x0000000000000076]
J 1854 c1 jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (89 bytes) @ 0x0000019dee8d071c [0x0000019dee8cfac0+0x0000000000000c5c]
J 1837 c1 jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (9 bytes) @ 0x0000019dee8ca5fc [0x0000019dee8ca4e0+0x000000000000011c]
J 1836 c1 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (76 bytes) @ 0x0000019dee8c9ed4 [0x0000019dee8c9c40+0x0000000000000294]
j  org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;Lorg/hibernate/cache/spi/access/EntityDataAccess;Lorg/hibernate/cache/spi/access/NaturalIdDataAccess;Lorg/hibernate/persister/spi/PersisterCreationContext;)Lorg/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister;+33
j  org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;Lorg/hibernate/cache/spi/access/EntityDataAccess;Lorg/hibernate/cache/spi/access/NaturalIdDataAccess;Lorg/hibernate/persister/spi/PersisterCreationContext;)Lorg/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister;+41
j  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataImplementor;Lorg/hibernate/metamodel/internal/JpaMetaModelPopulationSetting;)V+148
j  org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataImplementor;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;)V+662
j  org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build()Lorg/hibernate/SessionFactory;+69
j  org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build()Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;+20
j  org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(Ljavax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;+55
j  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory()Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;+129
j  org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory()Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;+1
j  org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()V+192
j  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()V+77
j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;)V+107
j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;)Ljava/lang/Object;+59
j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+249
j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+173
j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$227.getObject()Ljava/lang/Object;+16
j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory;)Ljava/lang/Object;+132
J 4110 c1 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object; (839 bytes) @ 0x0000019deed52b1c [0x0000019deed511c0+0x000000000000195c]
j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
j  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+9
j  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;)V+106
j  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh()V+54
j  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh()V+1
j  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)V+11
j  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;)V+2
j  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run([Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;+118
j  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run([Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;+9
j  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;+9
j  com.bgprotect.EmbeddedMain.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x00000004000000a3


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x00007fffe9a66ed6 jvm.dll
RAX=0x0000000400000003 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000094 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000014 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000030526fe140 points into unknown readable memory: 48 2a 46 ff 9d 01 00 00
RSP=0x00000030526fe0b0 points into unknown readable memory: 80 58 91 e5 9d 01 00 00
RBP=0x000000000000000c is an unknown value
RSI=0x000000000000000c is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000094 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000000000000c is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000030526fe258 points into unknown readable memory: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
R10=0x0000019dff4629a8 is pointing into metadata
R11=0x00000030526fe2d8 points into unknown readable memory: d9 0e 76 e9 ff 7f 00 00
R12=0x00000030526fe258 points into unknown readable memory: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
R13=0x00000000000003d8 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000019d8a35fdf0 points into unknown readable memory: 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
R15=0x00000030526fe140 points into unknown readable memory: 48 2a 46 ff 9d 01 00 00


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000400000003, RBX=0x0000000000000094, RCX=0x0000000000000014, RDX=0x00000030526fe140
RSP=0x00000030526fe0b0, RBP=0x000000000000000c, RSI=0x000000000000000c, RDI=0x0000000000000094
R8 =0x000000000000000c, R9 =0x00000030526fe258, R10=0x0000019dff4629a8, R11=0x00000030526fe2d8
R12=0x00000030526fe258, R13=0x00000000000003d8, R14=0x0000019d8a35fdf0, R15=0x00000030526fe140
RIP=0x00007fffe9a66ed6, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000030526fe0b0)
0x00000030526fe0b0:   0000019de5915880 00007fffe978233d
0x00000030526fe0c0:   00000000000000b2 0000000000000000
0x00000030526fe0d0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000030526fe0e0:   0000019d92e12390 0000019d92e12318
0x00000030526fe0f0:   000000000000000c 00000030526fe258
0x00000030526fe100:   000000000000000c 00000030526fe260
0x00000030526fe110:   0000019dff462a48 00007fffe9a2e1f2
0x00000030526fe120:   0000019dff462a48 00000030526fe260
0x00000030526fe130:   000000000000000c 00000030526fe258
0x00000030526fe140:   0000019dff462a48 0000019d8a9bd000
0x00000030526fe150:   0000019d92e12390 00007fffe9761455
0x00000030526fe160:   0000019dff462a48 00000030526fe420
0x00000030526fe170:   00000030526fe3f0 00007fffe9acd99b
0x00000030526fe180:   00007fffe9c9c901 0000019dff462a48
0x00000030526fe190:   0000019d8a9bd000 00007fff00000006
0x00000030526fe1a0:   0000019d8a9bd000 0000019d92e12318 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fffe9a66ed6)
0x00007fffe9a66dd6:   55 56 57 41 54 41 56 41 57 48 83 ec 30 4c 8b f1
0x00007fffe9a66de6:   4d 8b e1 48 8b 0a 41 8b e8 4c 8b fa 4c 8b 51 08
0x00007fffe9a66df6:   41 0f b7 42 28 41 0f b7 5a 34 c1 e3 02 33 d8 41
0x00007fffe9a66e06:   0f b7 42 32 c1 e3 02 33 d8 c1 e3 02 41 33 d8 48
0x00007fffe9a66e16:   83 3d 2b 5b 43 00 00 0f 84 99 00 00 00 8b 15 e3
0x00007fffe9a66e26:   db 45 00 65 48 8b 04 25 58 00 00 00 ff 05 e8 59
0x00007fffe9a66e36:   43 00 41 b8 08 00 00 00 4c 89 6c 24 70 48 8b 04
0x00007fffe9a66e46:   d0 4a 8b 14 00 48 8b ba 70 02 00 00 48 8b 47 28
0x00007fffe9a66e56:   48 8b 77 10 4c 8b 67 18 4c 8b 6f 20 48 89 44 24
0x00007fffe9a66e66:   78 e8 84 75 fc ff 8b 15 ae 59 43 00 48 8d 0d 87
0x00007fffe9a66e76:   14 29 00 4c 8b c8 89 5c 24 20 44 8b c5 e8 d8 f1
0x00007fffe9a66e86:   ff ff 48 83 3e 00 74 15 48 8b 54 24 78 48 8b cf
0x00007fffe9a66e96:   e8 35 31 af ff 48 8b ce e8 0d 31 af ff 4c 89 67
0x00007fffe9a66ea6:   18 4c 8b a4 24 88 00 00 00 4c 89 6f 20 4c 8b 6c
0x00007fffe9a66eb6:   24 70 48 89 77 10 8b fb 66 90 8b c7 25 1f 00 00
0x00007fffe9a66ec6:   80 7d 07 ff c8 83 c8 e0 ff c0 48 63 c8 49 8b 06
0x00007fffe9a66ed6:   48 8b 14 c8 48 85 d2 74 15 48 8b 02 48 85 c0 74
0x00007fffe9a66ee6:   0d 49 3b 07 75 08 0f b7 42 08 3b c5 74 79 ff c7
0x00007fffe9a66ef6:   8b c7 2b c3 83 f8 03 7c c1 45 33 c0 41 8d 50 01
0x00007fffe9a66f06:   8d 4a 3f e8 c2 9e ae ff 33 ff 44 8b c5 49 8b d7
0x00007fffe9a66f16:   48 8b c8 48 8b f0 48 89 38 48 c7 40 0c ff ff 00
0x00007fffe9a66f26:   00 66 89 78 08 48 89 78 18 48 89 78 20 48 89 78
0x00007fffe9a66f36:   28 48 89 78 30 e8 d0 f5 ff ff 48 8b d6 49 8b cc
0x00007fffe9a66f46:   e8 85 01 00 00 49 8b 0f e8 5d 8e fc ff 84 c0 74
0x00007fffe9a66f56:   49 48 8b ce 48 83 c4 30 41 5f 41 5e 41 5c 5f 5e
0x00007fffe9a66f66:   5d 5b e9 e3 9d ae ff 49 8b cc e8 5b 01 00 00 48
0x00007fffe9a66f76:   83 3d cb 59 43 00 00 0f 84 bc 00 00 00 8b d7 48
0x00007fffe9a66f86:   8d 0d ac 13 29 00 48 83 c4 30 41 5f 41 5e 41 5c
0x00007fffe9a66f96:   5f 5e 5d 5b e9 c1 f0 ff ff 90 8d 04 1f 25 1f 00
0x00007fffe9a66fa6:   00 80 7d 07 ff c8 83 c8 e0 ff c0 48 63 c8 49 8b
0x00007fffe9a66fb6:   06 48 8d 14 cd 00 00 00 00 48 8b 0c 02 48 85 c9
0x00007fffe9a66fc6:   75 17 49 03 16 45 33 c0 48 8b 05 1b 7d 3d 00 48 


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x0000019de5915880 points into unknown readable memory: 18 db ca e9 ff 7f 00 00
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x00007fffe978233d jvm.dll
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x00000000000000b2 is an unknown value
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x0000019d92e12390 points into unknown readable memory: 80 61 cb e9 ff 7f 00 00
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x0000019d92e12318 points into unknown readable memory: 18 62 cb e9 ff 7f 00 00


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x0000019d91e995f0, length=21, elements={
0x0000019de58fe000, 0x0000019dff42c000, 0x0000019dff42d800, 0x0000019d8a03b800,
0x0000019d8a03c800, 0x0000019d8a046000, 0x0000019d8a04d800, 0x0000019d8a072800,
0x0000019d89fc0800, 0x0000019d8a3aa000, 0x0000019d8a3ab000, 0x0000019d8a3ab800,
0x0000019d8a360800, 0x0000019d8c41f000, 0x0000019d94d91000, 0x0000019d8f7ec000,
0x0000019d8cede800, 0x0000019d8f364000, 0x0000019d8e2a3800, 0x0000019d9260d000,
0x0000019d90e5a800
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000019de58fe000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=16024, stack(0x0000003051300000,0x0000003051400000)]
  0x0000019dff42c000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15960, stack(0x0000003051a00000,0x0000003051b00000)]
  0x0000019dff42d800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10780, stack(0x0000003051b00000,0x0000003051c00000)]
  0x0000019d8a03b800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2312, stack(0x0000003051c00000,0x0000003051d00000)]
  0x0000019d8a03c800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3756, stack(0x0000003051d00000,0x0000003051e00000)]
  0x0000019d8a046000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13404, stack(0x0000003051e00000,0x0000003051f00000)]
  0x0000019d8a04d800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11248, stack(0x0000003051f00000,0x0000003052000000)]
  0x0000019d8a072800 JavaThread "Sweeper thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6376, stack(0x0000003052000000,0x0000003052100000)]
  0x0000019d89fc0800 JavaThread "Common-Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16080, stack(0x0000003052100000,0x0000003052200000)]
  0x0000019d8a3aa000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11824, stack(0x0000003052200000,0x0000003052300000)]
  0x0000019d8a3ab000 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6712, stack(0x0000003052300000,0x0000003052400000)]
  0x0000019d8a3ab800 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6124, stack(0x0000003052400000,0x0000003052500000)]
  0x0000019d8a360800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14972, stack(0x0000003052900000,0x0000003052a00000)]
  0x0000019d8c41f000 JavaThread "Catalina-utility-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4472, stack(0x0000003052b00000,0x0000003052c00000)]
  0x0000019d94d91000 JavaThread "Catalina-utility-2" [_thread_blocked, id=6408, stack(0x0000003052c00000,0x0000003052d00000)]
  0x0000019d8f7ec000 JavaThread "container-0" [_thread_blocked, id=2628, stack(0x0000003052d00000,0x0000003052e00000)]
  0x0000019d8cede800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=9280, stack(0x0000003052f00000,0x0000003053000000)]
  0x0000019d8f364000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-2" [_thread_in_native, id=2008, stack(0x0000003053000000,0x0000003053100000)]
  0x0000019d8e2a3800 JavaThread "HikariPool-1 housekeeper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7476, stack(0x0000003053200000,0x0000003053300000)]
  0x0000019d9260d000 JavaThread "HikariPool-1 connection adder" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16288, stack(0x0000003053400000,0x0000003053500000)]
  0x0000019d90e5a800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2700, stack(0x0000003051000000,0x0000003051100000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000019dff427800 VMThread "VM Thread" [stack: 0x0000003051900000,0x0000003051a00000] [id=9312]
  0x0000019d8a830000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000003052a00000,0x0000003052b00000] [id=4384]
  0x0000019de5913800 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#0" [stack: 0x0000003051400000,0x0000003051500000] [id=9504]
=>0x0000019d8a9bd000 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#1" [stack: 0x0000003052600000,0x0000003052700000] [id=6660]
  0x0000019d8ab2b000 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#2" [stack: 0x0000003052700000,0x0000003052800000] [id=14968]
  0x0000019d8af13000 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#3" [stack: 0x0000003052800000,0x0000003052900000] [id=7912]
  0x0000019de5971800 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Main Marker" [stack: 0x0000003051500000,0x0000003051600000] [id=12512]
  0x0000019de5978000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Conc#0" [stack: 0x0000003051600000,0x0000003051700000] [id=13048]
  0x0000019dff30d000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Refine#0" [stack: 0x0000003051700000,0x0000003051800000] [id=6112]
  0x0000019dff30e000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Young RemSet Sampling" [stack: 0x0000003051800000,0x0000003051900000] [id=5864]

Threads with active compile tasks:
C2 CompilerThread05281       4       org.eclipse.jdt.launching.internal.org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter::visitIntInsn (113 bytes)
C2 CompilerThread15106       4       org.eclipse.jdt.launching.internal.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter::toByteArray (1281 bytes)

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x0000019de58f6d70] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000019dff427800
[0x0000019de58fb5d0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0000019de58fe000

Heap address: 0x0000000701a00000, size: 4070 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000800000000, Narrow klass shift: 0
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000800000000

Heap:
 garbage-first heap   total 315392K, used 157226K [0x0000000701a00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  region size 1024K, 136 young (139264K), 7 survivors (7168K)
 Metaspace       used 58461K, capacity 59571K, committed 59692K, reserved 1101824K
  class space    used 7248K, capacity 7695K, committed 7808K, reserved 1048576K
Heap Regions: E=young(eden), S=young(survivor), O=old, HS=humongous(starts), HC=humongous(continues), CS=collection set, F=free, A=archive, TAMS=top-at-mark-start (previous, next)

END.
```

What other information is needed?

Comment: That looks like rather the Java VM fails to run/debug your application than Eclipse. Or does Eclipse crash? Maybe your Java installation is broken or maybe you run into a bug of your outdated Java 11.0.4.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated to OpenJDK 64-Bit (11.0.6+10)  and the VM crash is still happening. Eclipse does not crash , the Java process that i try to run is terminated prematurely

Comment: Looks similar to [Java bug JDK-8223062](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8223062): _"ClassLoader object has been created without running its constructor"_. In both cases bytecode manipulations are done, in the bug via Mockito, in your case via Byte Buddy. The Java bug says it's Mockito not Java. So in your case it might be Byte Buddy in combination with some misconfiguration of Spring.

Comment: Thanks , 'hibernate-core' (5.4.12.Final) is using 'byte-buddy', version: '1.10.7', upgrading to 'byte-buddy', version: '1.10.8' (latest)  did not solve the issue

Comment: It crashes from command line too, right? So find out what part of your code is causing the Java VM to crash.

Comment: Ahh, from command line it does not happen

Comment: The exact same command line that Eclipse executes? What about remote debugging?

Comment: Seems to work fine with remote debugging (this is good for me, thanks) , the command line is the same (but now i have to add -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044 to it)